# InitializationError while running Cucumber JUnit Tests

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, cucumber, bdd

```
package cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        format={"pretty"},
        features= "src/features/"
        )
public class cucumberRunner {

}
```

Using:

- cucumber-core-1.2.4
- cucumber-java-1.2.4
- cucumber-junit-1.2.4
- junit-4.12
- Eclipse Mars.1
- java 8

Error Trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/Element
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
>         at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
>         at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
>         at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:91)
>         at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:69)
>         at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.(Runtime.java:65)
>         at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.createRuntime(Cucumber.java:78)
>         at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.(Cucumber.java:58)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>         at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>         at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>         at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>         at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>         at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.Element
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 28 more

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your class is located in the package 'cucumber'.
Either rename the package or move your step-definitions and other glue-code to a sub-package like 'cucumber.steps' and restrict the lookup of glue-code to this package:

```
package cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

 @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
 @CucumberOptions(
    format={"pretty"},
    features= "src/features/",
    glue = "cucumber.steps")
 public class cucumberRunner {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has something do with the jars.Use this below dependency in your pom.xml file.
1.2.5 works!
For other versions, I was getting the same error but when I add this dependency, it worked for me without any errors!

```
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>1.2.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Import following lines to your code after adding that dependency in       your pom.xml file
-import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
-import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

Answer (score 0):

On your testRunner, make sure you import the correct Junit libraries. Once you hover your mouse on the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`, eclipse will provide you with two options, make sure NOT to select `"Add JUnit 4 Library to build path"`.

However, select `import 'RunWith'(org.junit.runner)` and import it. This will solve the error.

Answer (score -3):

Try importing the below,

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
```